# Is there free ERD tool mysql in unix suse 8?

Tags: mysql, unix

i have an older test unix server with mysql 4.1 enterprise edition on it.
i'm looking for a tool that i can use to automatically generate an erd?
preferably free and easy to setup...

i try to install workbench but i didn't have the know how and after checking with my server guys he told me that i can't install the latest version. and i've been googling around and i can't find any older version for workbench as well.

so i was thinking maybe there's some other open source tools hidden out there that i don't know about.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect) is one candidate.  I have not tried it with MySQL or on Linux but it reckons to support MySQL and it has a generic *nix download.  Plus it is FOSS.